# How can I convert C-String to LPCSTR on Windows

Tags: c, string, windows

In order to find if a file exists, I want to use the `GetFileAttributes` WinAPI function.

The function accepts a `LPCSTR` argument. How can I convert my classic `const char*` string to this type?

Please note, I'm using C, not C++. Is this the right way to go in C too?

Comment: Look up the definition of `LPCSTR` - I think you'll find that no conversion is required.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Microsoft documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types), LPCSTR is defined in WinNT.h as follows:

```
typedef __nullterminated CONST CHAR *LPCSTR;
```

This evaluates to `const char *`.

So, you are essentially asking how to convert `const char*` to itself. In other words, the answer to your question is that no conversion is required.

Regarding your question, there is no difference between C and C++. However, C++ offers additional ways of handling strings.

Answer (score 2):

It is `GetFileAttributesA` (note the `A`) which uses `LPCSTR`. The wide character version is `GetFileAttributesW`, and its argument is `LPCWSTR`.   The generic name `GetFileAttributes` is a shim which will switch between these two functions at compile time; it is defined in terms of a `TCHAR` `typedef` (`const` strings of which are `LPCTSTR`). `TCHAR` switches between `CHAR` or `WCHAR` based on whether you build the program for Unicode support.

If you have a `const char *` input intended to be passed to `GetFileAttributes` being compiled for Unicode, or to be passed to `GetFileAttributesW`, then a conversion is needed from byte string to wide string.

It's best to avoid mixing wide and narrow strings in the entire program, if at all possible, to avoid the cumbersome conversions.